# "The one who takes out more marbles wins" game

Tags: game-theory

There are two players, each has 20 marbles in their bag. There are 5 rounds and who wins more rounds will win the game. In each round, each player will take out a number of marbles. They can take out **0 marbles** for **one round** only when they still have marbles). The one who takes out more marble wins (can be a draw if marbles are equal) and **the marbles which are taken out by both players will be discarded**.

A player will know how many marbles that the other player takes out. If a player has no marble left, they will play the next rounds as if they take out 0 marbles.

What is the best strategy to play this game (in first round or any round, when winning or losing)?

Comment: So what happens if the bag becomes empty before the 5 rounds are finished? Must each player leave enough marbles for the 5 rounds to be fully played? If so, doesn't that mean that the second player of a round must know how many marbles are left and hence also what the first player took? If not, why can't the first player take everything, and win the only round that is played?

Comment: The title does not match the question.  The title seems to refer to the total number of marbles in winning rounds, the body refers to the number of winning rounds.  These are two different things.  For the title, a distribution of $17-1-1-1-0$ is tough, but not impossible, to beat.  For the body, that would be a poor choice.

Comment: I just updated the rule above. Both players know how many marbles other take out. If you dont have any marbles left, you will take out 0 marbles for the next rounds.

Comment: It is seems there are two bags of marbles. I previously read it as if there was one bag that they both take from.

Comment: Do they take out their marbles and then reveal it at the same time, or does one player get to react to the other's move in the same round?

Comment: They have to take out and reveal at the same time